# Why LDAP results are not shown outside of ApacheDS?

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I have installed LDAP server using ApacheDirectoryStudio and created various objects there.

When I use search within mentioned program it works fine but when I take url from "search logs" and use it in the browser, I am not getting what I created.

Why do I face this behavior?

**EDIT1:**

I only want to create user which will be available through LDAP URL. 
I tried to create some:
[find my screenshot from ApacheDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Gh8.png)

Then I take LDAP URL from the "search logs" which I marked yellow

e.g. ldap://localhost:10389/ou=users,ou=system?objectClass?sub?(objectClass=*)

and I try to load it in the browser(IE or Chrome). Here Windows contacts window opens and I am notified that there are no entries in the directory service that match your search criteria.

**EDIT2:**

When using LDAP browser I am getting following "Unable to perform Read entry operation." error:
[jxplorer unable to perform read entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr8sZ.png)

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added details what I do, but as I am very new in the topic I would prefer some explanation of how to think here rather than just solving the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve my issue.

1. I had to figure out that order in LDAP query matters.
2. That I can only see exactly what I query, no items in the subtree visible.
3. Disable option "Enable Access control"
4. Restarting LDAP server.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP within the URL "[ldap://](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20URL)" is called the Protocol "scheme".

Unfortunately most HTTP (http://) browsers do not support LDAP protocol.

HTTP Browsers used to support LDAP. Firefox used to. So did IE. Opera did.

So you use a [LDAP Browser](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Browsers) for LDAP and a HTTP [Browser](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Browser) for HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for this hint.
But when I access it via LDAP browser I cannot get results as I want neither.
In jxplorer when I click on some item in the tree I am getting:

"Unable to perform Read entry operation."

I have added detail into the post.